# Picking up audio using high speed video?

Tags: acoustics, vibrations

In the movie [*Eagle Eye*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eagle_Eye), ARIIA (an intelligence-gathering supercomputer/AI) picks up audio using video recording of the vibrations in a coffee cup. How close is this to reality?

I have see it done with laser on a window, and in theory I would imagine you could pick up 5 kHz audio by recording the vibrations with a 10,000 fps high speed hi-res camera.

Has it been done? How is the quality? What are the theoretical limitations? What are the practical limitations?

Comment: I spent a minute trying to figure out whatthehell a _"hires"_ camera was, then I realised you meant _"hi-res"_

Comment: If you can get close enough to video record a cup of coffee at high res, wouldn't it be easier to just use a microphone?

Comment: @hdhondt: If I recall correctly, in the movie the people went into an acoustically sealed room to have a private conversation about shutting ARIIA down. The AI spied on the cup to determine what was being said.

Comment: You're saying the AI could see but not hear? I suppose they gave it commands in sign language? I didn't see the movie, so I have trouble getting into the mind-set that makes it logical ;-)

Comment: Voting to keep open: I think that there is a physics component to this question aside from engineering: sound begets dynamic behaviour of the coffee, which can then be tracked by observing the change in the coffee's surface with time. So the answer is yes it could in principle be done quite aside from the particular technology needed to do it. There is also a question of how strong the effect is, again a pure physics question.

Comment: @hdhondt: The AI could understand verbal, visual, and computer input commands. The designers knew this and created an adjacent room that had no cameras & no microphones so that the AI couldn't spy in that room. However, there was a window and one of the characters left a coffee on the table and the AI watched the vibrations and recreated the conversation.

Comment: @Kyle Thanks for that - I will have to watch the movie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In today's news - researchers at MIT [did just that](http://newsoffice.mit.edu/2014/algorithm-recovers-speech-from-vibrations-0804) using high-speed camera with frame rate between 2 kHz and 6 kHz. They used some advanced filtering to detect microscopic movement of objects, but for details we will have to wait until they publish their paper.

Comment: Reading the news article and watching the video they also used normal cameras, where the electronics read of one scan line at a time. This gives them higher frequencies than the actual frame rate. And it suddenly made ARIIAs picking up audio from a coffee surface using a surveillance camera go from Hollywood fantasy to plausible.

Comment: Why a high-speed camera?  Can't they get the same information from a single-cell photosensor and a telescope?

Comment: @endolith No, they need highest possible camera resolution to resolve tiny movements. Even then, they they say that the movement is only about 1/100th of a pixel, so they would not be able to say anything from a single pixel. But take a million pixels, and then you can deduce something from synchronous changes in pixels' intensities.

Answer (score 2):

In principle, there is now reason that this can't be done.  There are, however, a lot of practical difficulties.

1. You would need a high speed camera recording at something like 50,000 fps to catch all of the audio band which humans can hear.  These things aren't cheap and generally can't record for longer than a few tens of seconds at such high speeds.  In contrast, [laser vibrometers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_Doppler_vibrometer) are relatively cheap and easy to build.
2. The surface you will be watching needs to have large contrast changes from the incident pressure waves.  Your example of the coffee cup probably would not work (unless the sounds were incredibly loud), it would need to be something more sensitive to pressure changes, like the [diaphragms used for speakers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaphragm_%28acoustics%29), with light reflecting off of it in just the right way.
3. The mechanical system which was responding to the pressure wave would need to be free of mechanical resonances in the audio band, or the mechanical resonances would need to be calibrated out.

All in all, I would say that this is a poor way to try and record sound, but it isn't a complete impossibility.  I don't know of any cases where it has been done in the past.

Comment: There is however [*this gadget*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thing_(listening_device)) that uses radio rather than light.

Comment: You don't need to capture 25kHz sound if you are interested in speech only. 2kHz would do just fine.

Comment: @gigacyan Very true.